# Finding "opposite" or closing character

Tags: java, string

I have a method strip() and here is the context of its use:

```
public String strip(String data, String tag)
{
   ...
}
@param data a string where all open symbols such as [({ have a matching close somewhere after them.
@param tag an opening symbol(such as "["    
@return a substring of the contents between the first given opening and the last corresponding closing character- with both characters removed.
example:

strip("caca blah blah [ hb {} ((stuff){okay} vv]","[")

should return "hb {}((stuff)(okay) vv"
```

My question - I have a solution in mind but I am trying to find a way to find the "opposite" or closing character of the one that is given, without coding all the possible combinations by hand. Is there some kind of trick or pattern with character coding, or possibly a utility method somewhere that does this?

Comment: "between the first given opening and the last corresponding closing character" is this really what you want? `a[b][c]d` would give `b][c`.

Comment: I am not really concerned with the method itself-its arbitrary, but thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the "opposite" character manually, there aren't very many. This can be done with a Map, paired sequences, interleaved sequences, switch statement, etc.. all can be hidden behind a nice tidy method.

---

While I *do not* recommend this (really, just use a Map/switch) this "fun" approach, complete with a guard, would work:

```
char closingOf(char c) {
    String opens = "(<[{";
    if (opens.indexOf(c) > -1) {
        // For "why" this works, see an ASCII character table. YMMV when
        // including other Unicode symbols.
        return c + (c < '<' ? 1 : 2);
    } else {
        return 0; // you get nothing
    }
}
```

This can also be done with paired sequences:

```
String opens  = "(<[{";
String closes = ")>]}";
int i = opens.indexOf(c);
return i > -1 ? closes.charAt(i) : 0;
```

Or with in an interleaved sequence:

```
String pairs = "()<>[]{}";
int i = pairs.indexOf(c);
return i > -1 && (i % 2) == 1 ? pairs.charAt(i + 1) : 0;
```

Or with a partially-scanned sequence:

```
String pairs = ")>]}(<[{";
int i = pairs.indexOf(c, 4);
return i > -1 ? pairs.charAt(i - 4) : 0;
```

Or if feeling practical-but-boring (this approach is a *good* contender against a Map for this case and I would probably use it; the switch is also easy to follow unlike some of the previous "fun" examples):

```
switch (c) {
    case '(': return ')';
    case '<': return '>';
    case '{': return '}';
    case '[': return ']';
    default: return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small map, something like:

```
HashMap<String, String> closingChar = new HashMap<>();
closingChar.put(")", "(");
closingChar.put("(", ")");
closingChar.put("}", "{");
closingChar.put("{", "}");
```

Then you look up any char in the map to find the corresponding character. The map above gives both the closing character given the opening one, and vice-versa - if you need only the former case, the 1st and 3rd put lines.